# React - render CSS animation onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, sorry if this is too basic.

I am trying to render a simple animation when `<Link>` is clicked in React.

I have **Coffees.jsx**:

```
import Brewing from './Brewing.jsx';

  handleClick() {
    return (<Brewing/>)
  }

  render(){
    return (
       <div>
        <div>
          <Link onClick={this.handleClick} to="/brewing">Coffee</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );       
  }
}

export default Menus;
```

and **Brewing.jsx**:

```
import './css/mug.css'

class Brewing extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="cup">
                <div className="coffee"></div>
              </div>
              <div className="smoke"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Brewing;
```

The above is not working. It only works if I inject the animation:

```
<div className="cup">
  <div className="coffee"></div>
</div>
<div className="smoke"></div>
```

directly into **Coffees.jxs**, like so:

```
 render(){
    return (
       <div>
        <div>
         <div className="cup">
          <div className="coffee"></div>
         </div>
         <div className="smoke"></div>  
          <Link to="/brewing"></Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );       
  }
```

But this is not desired...How do I render this animation at `onClick`?

EDIT:

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      isAuthenticated: false,
      messageName: null,
      messageType: null,
      select:'',
      email: '',
      id: '',
      username: '',
      active: '',
      admin: '',  
      //task:''
    };
    this.logoutUser = this.logoutUser.bind(this);
    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
    this.createMessage = this.createMessage.bind(this);
    this.removeMessage = this.removeMessage.bind(this);
    this.userId = this.userId.bind(this);
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
    };
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.userId();
  };
  getUsers() {
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/users`)
    .then((res) => { this.setState({ users: res.data.data.users }); })
    .catch((err) => { });
  };
  logoutUser() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false });
  };
  loginUser(token) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
    this.getUsers();
    this.createMessage('Welcome', 'success');
  };
  userId(event) {
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => { 
      console.log(res.data.data) 
      this.setState({
        select: res.data.data.select,
        email: res.data.data.email,
        id: res.data.data.id,
        username: res.data.data.username,
        active: String(res.data.data.active),
        admin: String(res.data.data.admin),
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
  createMessage(name='Sanity Check', type='success') {
    this.setState({
      messageName: name,
      messageType: type
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.removeMessage();
    }, 3000);
  };
  removeMessage() {
    this.setState({
      messageName: null,
      messageType: null
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar
          title={this.state.title}
          isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
        />
        <section className="section">
          <div className="container">
            {this.state.messageName && this.state.messageType &&
              <Message
                messageName={this.state.messageName}
                messageType={this.state.messageType}
                removeMessage={this.removeMessage} 
              />
            }
            <div className="columns">
              <div className="column is-half">
                <br/>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
                  <Route exact path='/register' render={() => (
                    <Form
                      formType={'Register'}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      loginUser={this.loginUser}
                      createMessage={this.createMessage}
                      userId={this.state.id} 
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/login' render={() => (
                    <Form
                      formType={'Login'}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      loginUser={this.loginUser}
                      createMessage={this.createMessage}
                      userId={this.state.id} 
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/logout' render={() => (
                    <Logout
                      logoutUser={this.logoutUser}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/status' render={() => (
                    <UserStatus
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/seeds' render={() => (
                    <Seeds
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      userId={this.state.id}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/menus' render={() => (
                    <Menus
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      userId={this.state.id}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/coffee' render={() => (
                    <Coffees
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      userId={this.state.select}
                    />
                  )} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have `Route` for `brewing`?

Comment: Can you post your Routes?

Comment: Don’t have any, should I?

Comment: Yes. If you are using `Link` then you should have `Route` to handle those `Link` clicks. Can you tell me what needs to be happen when someone clicks any Link. I just understood that when someone clicks `Link` animation should start, but what next?

Comment: Next a redirecion will happen to another route

Comment: That's what I asked, do you have Routes?

Comment: Yes. I would go to ‘/coffees’ next to animation being rendered and completed, using props.push.history

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197806/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-data-garden).

Comment: Hi @data_garden, check my answer and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click any `Link` it will not wait on that component to execute any event, it will simply `redirect` to given path `(to="/coffees")`, so you need Route to handle this path.

Instead of `Link` we can use a `button` or simply a `div` (you can style it so that it look like link) and write `onClick` handler on that. In that handler we need to add a `setTimeout` with the timeout of actual animation.

Now when `setTimeout` executes, we can set a variable in `state` which will help us to redirect to desired component.

Your menu component should be,

```
class Menu extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      redirect: false
    }
  }

  gotoCoffee = () => {
    this.setState({isLoading:true})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000)  //Replace this time with your animation time
  }

  renderCoffee = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to='/coffees' />
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.isLoading && <Brewing />}
        {this.renderCoffee()}
        <div onClick={this.gotoCoffee} style={{textDecoration:'underline',color:'blue',cursor:'pointer'}}>Go to Coffee</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have used [`Redirect`](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a) from `react-router-dom` package for navigation.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zqrpz2)

Comment: with your solution, redirection does not render and mount coffee component, it just points to it, but it only actually returns coffee with refresh at browser, redirection is not enough here.

Comment: Have you implemented the same way provided in Demo?

Comment: What is the issue? Demo is seems to fine and getting redirected after 5sec (animation time).

Comment: the issue is that I coffee component is not being mounted here. Only if I refresh at browser. url changes with your solution, but does not render my coffee template.

Comment: I have an open bounty about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532219/react-redirect-after-transition-not-working

Comment: From where you are passing `isAuthenticated`?

Comment: from `App.jsx`, which is not here on the question.

Comment: Show me how you are passing that.

Comment: When you say *url changes with your solution, but does not render my coffee template.*, are you getting `playlist` printed on the page?

Comment: no, I'm not getting playlist printed on the page. but with refresh I get it printed, and template rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198115/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-data-garden).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider with your `Menus` component;

- returning the `<Brewing>` JSX from `handleClick()` won't affect the rendering result of the `Menus` component, meaning that the animation in `<Brewing>` won't show as required
- you'll need to track some state to determine if the `<Link>` has been clicked by the user at which point, your `Menus` component can render the `<Brewing>` component (ie that contains the animation)

One way to approach that in code would be to make the following changes in Coffee.jsx:

```js
import Brewing from './Brewing.jsx';

class Menus extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    /* 
    Set inital state to false, which means Brewing wont initially show 
    */
    this.state = { hasBeenClicked : false };
  }

}

handleClick() {
  /* 
  Set hasBeenClicked state of Menus to true after click which will
  cause Brewing to be rendered 
  */
  this.setState({ hasBeenClicked : true });
}

render(){
    return (
     <div>
        <div>
          { /* 
            This is short hand for "if hasBeenClicked = true, then 
            render Brewing here 
            */ }
          { (this.state.hasBeenClicked === true) && <Brewing/> }              
          <Link onClick={this.handleClick} to="/brewing">Coffee</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );       
  }
}

export default Menus;
```