# React <Redirect> after transition not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component which has a redirection route after an animation is finished, like so:

**Menus.jsx**

```
class Menus extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        select: 'espresso',      
        isLoading: false,
        redirect: false
    };

  gotoCoffee = () => {
    this.setState({isLoading:true})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000)  //Replace this time with your animation time
  }

  renderCoffee = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return (<Redirect to={`/coffee/${this.state.select}`} />)
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">Menu</font></h1>
        <hr/><br/>
        <div>
           {this.state.isLoading && <Brewing />}
           {this.renderCoffee()}
          <div onClick={this.gotoCoffee} 
               style={{textDecoration:'underline',cursor:'pointer'}}>
              <strong><font color="#C86428">{this.state.coffees[0]}</font></strong></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );       
  }
}

export default withRouter(Menus);
```

The animation called `onCLick`:

**Brewing.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './css/mug.css'

class Brewing extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="cup">
                <div className="coffee"></div>
              </div>
              <div className="smoke"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Brewing);
```

And here redirected route component:

**Coffee.jsx**

```
class Coffees extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        select:'',
        template:''
    };
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getCoffee();
    }
  };
  getCoffee(event) {
    //const {userId} = this.props
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/coffee/espresso`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.data)
      this.setState({
        template: res.data.data[0].content
      })
    })    
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };

    render(){
        var __html = this.state.template;
        var template = { __html: __html };

        return (
           <div id="parent">
           <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">{this.state.select} playlist</font></h1>
            <hr/><br/>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Coffees);
```

but `<Redirect>` in **Menus.jsx** is not working....url changes at browser but nothing happens; only if I refresh the browser `/coffee` is sucessfully mounted.

---

> What I actually need to happen:

1. render Menu
2. click on a link
3. click renders an animation
4. when animation is done, after 5 seconds,
5. `<Redirect>` to `/coffee`

what am I missing?

Comment: Could you add a codesandbox, it is easier to help with runnable code. Did you forget to close your ` Menus Component ` constructor bracket ` `}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say *url changes at browser but nothing happens; only if I refresh the browser `/coffee` is sucessfully mounted.*

This might be the issue with your `Routes`.

When you `redirect` to path `/coffee/${this.state.select}`, you should have `Route` to handle this path.

```
<Route path="/coffee/:select?" render={() => ( <Coffees isAuthenticated={true}/> )}/>
```

**Note:** Be aware of adding `exact` prop to `Route`. When you add `exact` prop it means your path should match exactly with all the provided params.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `getCoffee` function in also `componentDidUpdate` function.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getCoffee();
    }
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getCoffee();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Redirect should be inside the `render()`.

```
render(){
    if(this.state.redirect) {
        return(<Redirect to={`/coffee/${this.state.select}`} />)
    } else {
        return ( 
            <div>
               ...your component
            </div> ); 
    }
}
```

Note that this way you shouldn't need your `renderCoffee()` function.

I'm on mobile so i wasn't able to test if it works. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: this does not work...you must include the transition part in your answer, which was disregaded. with your answer transition disappeared

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Menu component construtor has no closing bracket.

```
...

class Menus extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        select: 'espresso',      
        isLoading: false,
        redirect: false
    };
  } // did you miss this?

gotoCoffee = () => {

...
```

Comment: the missing { is a typo, there's no syntax problem